# How to convert a string representation of unicode literals from a file, into real unicode literals using python 3?

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, literals

I got a file with plain text and some representation of unicode literals such as

```
STRING_LITERAL2 = '"' ( ([^\x22\x5C\xA\xD]) | '\' [tbnrf\"'] )* '"'
```

I need to interpret these representations into real literals and use them in a regular expression. The problem is, if I simple read them, I get

```
str_lit2 = ('\'"\' ( ([^\\x22\\x5C\\xA\\xD]) | \'\\\' [tbnrf\\"\'] )* \'"\''
```

and the `import.re` package of python can't interpret these literals.

I can find the specific representations using `re.sub("\\\\x",...)` but if I want to replace them `re.sub("\\\\x","\\x".encode().decode('unicode_escape'), str_lit2)` - to say these are real literals - I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

So how can I convert these string representatives of unicode literals into real literals? Of course only for python3, because I need to use this.

Greetings
Meldamos

Answer (score 0):

All the hexadecimal characters you include all fall into the US_ASCII plane since none of them have their most significant bit set. For example, `\x22`is equivalent to the Unicode/ASCII quote `"`. Similarly `\5c` is equivalent to the Unicode/ASCII `\`.

Without further clarification from you, I assume you are over-quoting normal ASCII codepoints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't see the meaning in telling me this. Currently I'm trying to parse the definitions of W3C Prov-N notation into a regular expression to tokenize a provenance document. But for what do you need this information? My problem has something to do with the difference between string representation and truly literal and how to convert one into the other. Maybe got some other ideas or solutions?